# Angularjs history support for IE6 and IE7

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-7, browser-history, hashchange, jquery-bbq

I am using **routing** in `Angularjs` for my SPA but I have to support IE7 (and IE8 in IE7 compatibility mode). I want the browser history to still work though. I don't care if I have to use a jQuery plugin.

Comment: The 90's called. They want their href's back.

Comment: @DanKanze - Sadly.. where I work there is an internal system so immersed with IE7 that they cannot upgrade beyond IE8 with compatibility mode.

Comment: Yes, they can.  They can use IE 7/8 for the legacy app, and Chrome or Firefox for everything else.  Unless they're drinking Microsoft's Kool-Aid.  Legacy apps like this are the only reason to use IE.  Ever.

Comment: @iconoclast - I completely agree and have taken that stance where possible. Not all IT management think that way, but slowly, the world is changing for the better.

Comment: Not all IT management think.  Period.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I checked through the angular source **sniffer.js**, **location.js** and **browser.js** to check the mechanics of how history is working. In essence if the browser supports history (i.e. `$sniffer.history` is true) then history api is used, else it simply writes to `location.href` (or `locaiton.replace(url)`). Check out `$browser.url(url, replace)` in **browser.js**, line 149 for details.

So, if angular is just writing to `location` then a jquery plugin like [Ben Alman](http://benalman.com/)'s [BBQ](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) will pick up this event because it is polling for changes to location.hash. I have successfully got this working in IE8 (in IE7 mode) by simply including Ben's [hashchange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) (a subset of BBQ) and then a minimal event fire and event listening:

```
$(function () {
  $(window).hashchange(function() {
    // don't delete this empty handler or ie6/7 history won't work.
  });
  // call hashchange on first load
  $(window).hashchange();
});
```

NOTE: jQuery hashchange (and BBQ) is using deprecated `$.browser.msie` at **line 300** so instead use `(document.documentMode != undefined)` as suggested in the comments to Ben's blog post.